# Are there any cell properties that you can use to terminate a cellgroup without starting a new one?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

Suppose I have the following notebook:

```
nb = Notebook[
    {
        Cell[
            CellGroupData[
                    {
                        Cell["Chapter 1", "Chapter"],
                        Cell["opening text", "Text"],
                        Cell[
                            CellGroupData[
                                {
                                        Cell[
                                            "Section 1", "Subsection", 
         CellGroupingRules -> {"GroupTogetherGrouping", 10000.}
                                        ],
                                        Cell[
                                            "section text", "Text", 
         CellGroupingRules -> {"GroupTogetherGrouping", 10000.}
                                        ],
                                        Cell[
                                            "section ends here", "Text", 
         CellGroupingRules -> {"GroupTogetherGrouping", 10000.}
                                        ]
                                    },
                                Open
                            ]
                        ],
                        Cell["text in Chapter 1 but not in Section 1", "Text"]
                    },
                    Open
                ]
        ],
        Cell @ CellGroupData[
                {Cell["Chapter 2", "Chapter"], Cell["more text", "Text"]},
                Open
            ]
    }
];
NotebookPut[nb]
```

[image]

Note how I used the `CellGroupingRules` (inserted using the Cell -> Grouping menu item) to end the section and create a text cell at the end of the chapter that's outside of the section.

My question is: is there a way to do this without giving all the cells in the section the `CellGroupingRules -> {"GroupTogetherGrouping", someHighNumber}` option? I'm looking for a solution (if it exists) where, instead, you can give last cell of the section (or the first cell outside the section) some option/property that ends the section without starting a new one. So something like:

```
NotebookPut @ Notebook[{
    Cell["Chapter 1", "Chapter"],
    Cell["opening text", "Text"],
    Cell["Section 1", "Subsection"],
    Cell["section text", "Text"],
    Cell["section ends here", "Text", someOption -> someValue],
    Cell["text in Chapter 1 but not in Section 1", "Text", someOtherOption -> someOtherValue],
    Cell["Chapter 2", "Chapter"],
    Cell["more text", "Text"]
}]
```

where the settings for `someOption` and `someOtherOption` produce the same result as before.